# How do I map keys from two different dictionaries to each other?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to map the keys of one dictionary to the keys of another dictionary to create a new dictionary. (The dictionaries are sorted in the order I want them to map up.)

For example:

```
Letter_Freq = {}
Letter_Freq2 = {'a':8,'b':6,'c':2}
Letter_Freq4 = {'e':24,'g':4,'f':3}
```

Wanted output:

```
{'a':'e', 'b':'g','c':'f'}
```

I've tried several things, but nothing works.

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
    for key0 in Letter_Freq2:
        for key1 in Letter_Freq4: 
            Letter_Freq[key0] = key1
```

This doesn't work. It just returns

```
{'a':'e', 'b':'e', 'c:'e'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use nested loops when you want one-to-one mapping. Nested loops create a cross-product. And in this case, you repeatedly assign the same keys, and just get the final assignment.

Use `zip()` to iterate over sequences in parallel. You don't need loops, you can simply pass this to the `dict()` constructor:

```
Letter_Freq = dict(zip(Letter_Freq2, Letter_Freq4))
```

Comment: Yeah, I frequently lose the races because I like to include explanations.

Comment: I usually do too (look at some of my answers, they're quite long-winded :D) but sometimes I break rank and this is what happens lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for k1, k2 in zip(Letter_Freq2, Letter_Freq4):
   Letter_Freq[k1] = k2
```